# PIP equivalent for installing pre-built binaries from the unofficial Python pre-built repository

Tags: python, libraries

It's quite often that people need to install pre-built binaries of common Python libraries. Although PIP is great, it often can't build the binaries itself as many of these binaries rely on other libraries to be present.

Is there a PIP equivalent that can download and install pre-built binaries from the [unofficial Python repository for Windows binaries of the libraries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: ...and why the official way is to build on every installation? We should save time and energy having packages built only once.